# ktor test faild with 'Response has already been sent'

Tags: kotlin, junit, jetbrains-ide, ktor

I trying to create API with ktor.
Test for ktor api using JUnit5 and I need use the custom properties for database information in 'Application.conf' like below:

```
ktor {
    deployment {
        .....
    }

    application {
        .....
    }

    database {
        host = ${?DB_HOST}
        user = ${?DB_USER}
        pass = ${?DB_PASS}
    }
}
```

I following official guidline for useing custom properties:
[HoconApplicationConfig](https://ktor.io/docs/testing.html#hocon)

```kotlin
private val testEnv = createTestEnvironment {
    config = HoconApplicationConfig(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
}

class MyTest {
    @Test
    fun Testing() {
        withApplication(testEnv) {
            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/foo").apply {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Succeed test when only one function in class, but defined second test function then test failed with Exception.
I want define multiple function to simplify the definition and checking in case of failure.

```kotlin
class MyTest {
    @Test
    fun Testing() {
        withApplication(testEnv) {
            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/foo").apply {
                ....
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun Testing2() {
        withApplication(testEnv) {
            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/foo/bar").apply {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
io.ktor.server.engine.BaseApplicationResponse$ResponseAlreadySentException: Response has already been sent
```

I know all test will success using 'withTestApplication' but can't use the  custom properties.
How can I use the custom properties, and define multiple test funcitons?

Environment:

- macOS Big Sur 11.5
- IntelliJ Ultimate 2021.1.3
- kotlin 1.5.21
- ktor 1.6.1
- junit-jupiter 5.7.0

Sorry for bad English.
Best Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is a sample project https://github.com/Stexxe/hocon_test/. Could you please share your project? Also, please provide a full stack trace of `ResponseAlreadySentException`.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman
Thank you for answer and made a sample project.
I realized to difference between yours and mine that scope of `testEnv`.
I move it to global scope to class scope then all test function were succeed.
Thank you so much.

(but why...)